# PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32 count last minute

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, system.diagnostics

How to count the total increment of last minute?

```
        //Create Counter
        CounterCreationDataCollection counter = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

        CounterCreationData total = new CounterCreationData();
        total.CounterName = "totalOps";
        total.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32;
        counter.Add(total);
```

Comment: can you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: Please check  the answer.its helping for you issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238212/counter-of-type-rateofcountspersecond32-always-shows-0

Comment: Arshad: Is there a property like PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerMintue64?. RameshRams: the link didn't help me