# Assign a float value to performance counter

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have created a performance counter in C#. However, when assigning a value to it, I would like the value to be a `float` instead of `long`, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do so. Can anybody help?

The code I am using is from [Counter of type RateOfCountsPerSecond32 always shows 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238212/counter-of-type-rateofcountspersecond32-always-shows-0):

```
public static void Test()
{
    var ccdc = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    // Add the counter.
    const string counterName = "RateOfCountsPerSecond64Sample";
    var rateOfCounts64 = new CounterCreationData
    {
        CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond64,
        CounterName = counterName
    };
    ccdc.Add(rateOfCounts64);

    // Create the category.
    const string categoryName = "RateOfCountsPerSecond64SampleCategory";
    if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName))
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(categoryName);
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(categoryName, "",
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, ccdc);

    // create the counter
    var pc = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, false);
    pc.RawValue = 1000; // <-- want to assign a float value here
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: RawValue is a long property so why do you want to assign float value to a long property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and if you think about it, it wouldn't make any sense. Counters *count* distinct events and you can't have half an event. Counters can only be incremented as events occur.

A rate counter actually calculates the difference of a base counter between intervals for display purposes. The `PerSecond` counters use a system-provided interval counter that increments every second. You only have to increment the counter whenever events occur and the OS will calculate the rate.

Other counters that calculate averages allow you to increment the base counter as well, so you can have eg. `Bytes per Packet` counters

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't; the data type is `long`. Just scale it by some factor instead (so you get to keep a few decimal places, as low digits) - x1000, for example - and round it:

```
pc.RawValue = (long)(value * 1000);
```

However, since you're using `RateOfCountsPerSecond32` - you should be recording totals, not the rate. The backend computes the rate.